# Simple word scrabble code using python that takes command line parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a simple word scrabble script that finds words score values. The script should reads two parameters from the command line and display the best word value, which returns the word with highest point value. I have created a constructor that reads the file and populate a dictionary of letter/value for use with the remaining methods of the class. For example the command line parameters should look like the following:

```
scrabble.py c:\tiles.txt apple,squash  
Output: The best value is squash with 18.
```

Here is what I have so far. I know that import argv is helful, but not sure how to get started.

```
from sys import argv

class Scrabble:
    def __init__(self, tilesFile):
        with open(tilesFile, "r") as f:
            lines = [ line.strip().split(":") for line in f ]

        self.tiles = { k:int(v) for k,v in lines }

    def getWordValue(self, word):
        sum = 0
        for letter in word.upper():
            sum += self.tiles[letter]

        return sum

    def getBestWord(self):
        pass


def main():
    s1 = Scrabble("tile_values.txt")
    value = s1.getWordValue("hello")
    print(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
   pass
```

Comment: What's the specific problem that's keeping you from being able to do this?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not sure how to use input from command line parameters, instead of using  python input--- value = s1.getWordValue("hello")

Comment: Are you unsure how to *use* the input, or unsure how to *get* the input?

Comment: Unsure how to use the input from command line parameters

Comment: You could initialize a `Scabble` object, and then call the `getWordValue()` method on the input argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>What you need is to use the `argparse` module
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html</strike>

I took your example and added argparse. There are some issues with your Scrabble constructor. But you will get the idea of using args on the command line

`python scrabble.py tiles.txt apple squash orange`

```
import argparse
import sys

class Scrabble:
    def __init__(self, tilesFile):
        with open(tilesFile, "r") as f:
            lines = [ line.strip().split(":") for line in f ]

        self.tiles = { k:int(v) for k,v in lines }

    def getWordValue(self, word):
        sum = 0
        for letter in word.upper():
            sum += self.tiles[letter]

        return sum

    def getBestWord(self):
        pass


def main(argv):
    s1 = Scrabble(argv[1])
    if len(argv) < 3:
        print 'no words given'
        sys.exit(1) 

    # argv[2:] means the items in argv starting from the 3rd item.
    # the first item will be the name of the script you are running
    # the second item should be the tiles file. 
    for word in argv[2:]:
        value = s1.getWordValue(word)
        print(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main(argv)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am student and my professor wants us to import argv from sys. Anyway you can help me with that?

Comment: Take a look. Just remember to add some good error checking in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the arguments you script was passed on the command line with `sys.argv`.

```
from sys import argv
print("This is a list of all of the command line arguments: ", argv)
```